# Hyperledger Composer ACL: read access for different participants

Tags: acl, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have 3 different participants identified by own ID: Provider, Requester and Consumer. Provider should be able to see bank account of Requester but not from Consumer. How can I define the rule?

First the model file:

```
namespace org.acme.biznet

abstract participant Member identified by memberId {
o String memberId
o String name
o String email
}

// Sensorbesitzer, z.B private Personen, Haushalte etc.
participant Provider identified by providerId extends Member {
o String providerId
--> SDTWallet sdtWallet
--> BTCWallet btcWallet
--> Account account
}

// Sensordatenabnehmer, z.B unabhängiger Dienstleister
participant Requester identified by requesterId extends Member {
o String requesterId
--> SDTWallet sdtWallet
--> Account account
}

// Datenkonsument, der die aufbereitete Sensordaten kauft, z.B Behörden, 
Regierung etc.
participant Consumer identified by consumerId extends Member {
o String consumerId
--> Account account
}
// Geldkonto von den Netzwerkteilnehmern.
asset Account identified by accountId {
o String accountId
o Double balance default = 0.0
--> Member owner 
}
```

As I mentioned, Provider should be able to see, the Account of his own and Account of Requester.

```
rule ProvidersReadAccesstoAccount {
description: "Providers have read access to own Account and Account of 
Requester"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ
resource: "org.acme.biznet.Account"
action: ALLOW
}
```

With this rule I see all 3 of them. I created this one:

```
rule ProvidersNoAccessToAccount {
description: "Providers have no access to Account of Consumer"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ
resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Account"
condition: (r.owner.getIdentifier() == "org.acme.biznet.Consumer")    
action: DENY
}
```

But it won't work. How should it be defined?

Comment: can you edit your question to include all your ACL rules, and your model file?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to replace your last rule with something like this one (below) ?  Use `getFullyQualifiedType()` to get it as shown: (FYI `getIdentifier()` gets the actual id of the owner participant eg '123' ).

```
rule DenyProviderAccessToConsumer {
    description: "Disallow Provider -> Consumer"
    participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
    operation: READ
    resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Account"
    condition: (r.owner.getFullyQualifiedType() == "org.acme.biznet.Consumer")   
    action: DENY
}
```

and also - this 'more succinct' rule should be above your more 'broad'  rule `ProvidersReadAccesstoAccount` in the file permissions.acl so that that rule is evaluated after the rule I provided above.

Comment: That works. though it's strange for me, that the rules depends their places in the permissions.acl file.

Comment: they work on an evaluation match ; if the broader rule provides a match (eg ALLOW) on the target resource first, then the 'DENY' rule for the few, won't be evaluated ; it will never reach that part of the acl rules if its lower down.